# Pycharm console is blank

Tags: python, pycharm

I cannot get a prompt to appear in my Pycharm console. This appears to have something to do with an error that appears on startup:

```
Error: Cannot start process, the path specified for working directory is not a directory
```

I have looked at these threads and attempted solutions where I could:

[Working directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202273/working-directory-error)

[How can I run my currently edited file in a PyCharm console in a way that I can type into the command line afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609581/how-can-i-run-my-currently-edited-file-in-a-pycharm-console-in-a-way-that-i-can)

[Interacting with program after execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207019/interacting-with-program-after-execution)

[Does Pycharm have Interactive Python Interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709105/does-pycharm-have-interactive-python-interpreter)

[Cannot start a console in newly installed Pycharm in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192068/cannot-start-a-console-in-newly-installed-pycharm-in-windows)

[PyCharm and Python Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589951/pycharm-and-python-console)

[Pycharm interactive console does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332194/pycharm-interactive-console-does-not-work)

Unlike [Cannot start a console in newly installed Pycharm in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192068/cannot-start-a-console-in-newly-installed-pycharm-in-windows) , I have no error message to go on; just a blank spot where I expected some `>>>`. I'm using Pycharm Community Edition 4.5. I'm using Mac OS 10.10.5, and sys.version in Python yields this.

```
'2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]'
```

Despite a bad experience so far, I'm hoping to persist with Pycharm because it gets good reviews from my Python-savvy friends and family. Can I add any information to make this issue solvable? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was solved by re-starting Pycharm, closing all files, and choosing a folder, rather than a file, for a new project. Solution inspired by [Working directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202273/working-directory-error) .

This also allowed me to access the correct one out of my distressingly numerous available Python installations.

Answer (score 1):

When I have had this problem with an existing project, one or both of the following two actions has resolved it:

1. Reset your Console configuration in the Pycharm Settings dialogue, particularly anything that involves directories.
2. Close Pycharm, remove the .idea directory from the project, re-open Pycharm, and rebuild your Pycharm settings for the project from scratch. Especially after upgrading Pycharm. Stuff just breaks sometimes and their application logging is pretty terrible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by closing Pycharm then editing the `.idea/workspace.xml` and removing completely the section:

```
  <component name="DjangoConsoleOptions" (...)>
    <option name="myCustomStartScript" (...) />
  </component>
```

Comment: worked for me also. I removed both sections.
<component name="DjangoConsoleOptions" ...>.. </component>
<component name="PyConsoleOptionsProvider"> ..</component>